# Error when executing snapcraft cleanbuild /snap/snapcraft/794/bin/snapcraft-classic: 5: exec: /snap/snapcraft/794/usr/bin/python3: not found

Tags: linux, snapcraft

I am trying to make my first snap with snapcraft, and i finished the actual app, but when I ran 'snapcraft build', I got this error

```
/snap/snapcraft/794/bin/snapcraft-classic: 5: exec: /snap/snapcraft/794/usr>/bin/python3: not found
```

I then checked that same file path and that file did exist. Help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: please provide more details when asking a question

Comment: Operating System: Linux Mint 18, what all details should I provide?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @SameeraSampath what other details should I provide?

Comment: Please provide the snap file. We can take a look and see if your pre-reqs are installed.